# Access SQL query involving Switch statement VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

```
If Demographic = "Age" Then
Demographic = "SELECT COUNT(CustomerID) As Result, Switch(
  DateDiff(yyyy, DOB, Date()) >40, 40,
  DateDiff(yyyy, DOB, Date()) >25, 25,
  DateDiff(yyyy, DOB, Date()) >20, 20,
  DateDiff(yyyy, DOB, Date()) >10, 10
) AS Age_Group 
FROM tblCustomer
GROUP BY Switch(
  DateDiff(yyyy, DOB, Date()) >40, 40,
  DateDiff(yyyy, DOB, Date()) >25, 25,
  DateDiff(yyyy, DOB, Date()) >20, 20,
  DateDiff(yyyy, DOB, Date()) >10, 10
), Result"
```

I have been trying to use a select case statement to create a graph of the number of records within each age group from the date of birth and the current date. I keep getting the error

> No value given for one or more required parameters.

And I have no idea why, any help with this or just a better method would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if this related to the error, but don't group by `Result`. Group only by the non-aggregated columns.

Comment: My suggestion would be to filter out null values by using "not null"  The null fields may cause it a select case to fail.

Comment: One issue here is that `DateDiff` expects a string for its first argument. Use `DateDiff('yyyy'` instead of `DateDiff(yyyy`

Answer (score 0):

Remove Result from the groupby.